# How i can create a button with mutiple conditions in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I don't know what the question would be exactly but i know that the solution to this problem is done with conditions or maybe i'm wrong but it's what i found by googling.

I am trying to create a button to play a video but i want to make it more dynamic and get this result:

[image]

The problem is that i don't know how to hide the pause/play while the video is loading and the spinner appears, and when the video ends the spinner continues to appear the text does not change from pause to play, this is my code:

I'm using [Expo Video](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/)

```
export default class Video extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {params} = props.navigation.state;
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      mute: true,
      shouldPlay: false,
      isPlaying: false
    };
  }

  handlePlayAndPause = () => {  
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
       shouldPlay: !prevState.shouldPlay,
    }));

  }


  render() {

  const {item} = this.state;  
  const {isPlaying} = this.state;  
  const {shouldPlay} = this.state;  

    return (

<Video
    source={{ uri: item.url_video }}
    shouldPlay={this.state.shouldPlay}
    resizeMode="contain"
    isLooping={false}
    isMuted={this.state.mute}
    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => {
    this.setState({isPlaying: status.isPlaying});
    }}
  />

  <Button onPress={this.handlePlayAndPause}>
  <Icon name={isPlaying ? "pause-circle-filled" : "play-circle-filled"} />
  <Text>{isPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}</Text>
  <ActivityIndicator animating={!isPlaying && shouldPlay} size="small" color="#ffffff" />
  </Button>


    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the log into a separate render function like so:

```
renderButton = () => {
  const { isLoading, isPlaying, shouldPlay } = this.state;
  if(isLoading) {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator animating={!isPlaying && shouldPlay} size="small" color="#ffffff" />
    );
  }
  const label = isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play';
  const iconName = isPlaying ? 'pause-circle-filled' : 'play-circle-filled';
  return (
    <>
      <Icon name={iconName} />
      <Text>{label}</Text>
    </>
  )
}

render() {
  return (
    <Button onPress={this.handlePlayAndPause}>{this.renderButton()}</Button>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the indicator should appear when I hit play and disappear when the video starts and when the video ends, the text play appears again, how can I get that?